# On Form submission PHP file opens as a new page rather than executing script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created a contact form that is to be validated via ajax PHP and then emailed using PHP.

When I click submit, instead of carrying out the PHP script and validating, the page reloads at a new page:

mypage.com/form_process.php

Also, it does not load the stylesheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src= "https//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <?php include('form_process.php'); ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function) {
            $("form").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = $("name").val();
                var email = $("email").val();
                var signature = $("signature").val();
                $(".form-message").load("form_process.php", {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    signature: signature
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contact-form">
        <form  method="post" action="form_process.php" method="POST" name="pdf-download">
            <div class="podrecieved">
                <h3>Recieved by<h3>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label for="firstname">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="John Doe">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label for="email_id">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email_id" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="john@company.com">
            </div>
            <div>                 
                <label for="messages">
                    <span class="required">Additional Comments:</span> 
                    <textarea id="messages" name="messages" placeholder="Please write your thougths here." tabindex="5"></textarea> 
                </label>  
            </div>   
            <div class="container">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h3>Click to sign</h3>
                                <input type="text" id="txt" name="signature" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="editor"></div>  
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
            <p class="form-message"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

form_process.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $signature = $_POST['signature'];
    $message = $_POST['messages'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];

    $ErrorEmpty = false;
    $ErrorEmail = false;

    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($signature)){
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Please fill in required fields</span>";
        $ErrorEmpty = true;
    }
    elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Please fill in a valid email address</span>";
        $ErrorEmail = true;
    }
    else {
        echo "<span class='form-success'>Please fill in a valid email address</span>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "There was an Error!";
}

$mailto = "contact@email.co.uk";
$headers = "from:".$company;
$txt = "Your Proof of delivery was signed for by:".$name;

mail($mailto, $headers, $txt );
header("location: index.php?POD_sent");
?>

<script>
    $("#name, #email, #txt").removeClass(input-error);

    var ErrorEmpty = "<?php echo $ErrorEmpty; ?>";
    var ErrorEmail = "<?php echo $ErrorEmail; ?>";

    if(ErrorEmpty == true) {
        $("#name, #email, #txt").addClass("input-error");
    } 
    if(ErrorEmail == true) {
        $("#email").addClass("input-error");
    }
    if(ErrorEmpty == false && ErrorEmail == false) {
        $("#name, #email, #txt").val("")
    }
</script>
```

I cannot see where I have gone wrong with this code. Rather than opening a new link to `form_process.php` it should use form_process.php to validate then send the form.

The `form_process.php` seems to being called as I am getting the error - `There was an Error!` from the line `else{
    echo "There was an Error!";
}`

So I am assuming the error comes from this sheet`form_process.php`

Comment: Have you thougt about to remove the `<?php include('form_process.php'); ?>` from your code and the `form_process` returns a json instead? On json execution you can do fancy stuff such as html manululation. Just keep it simple and let the http error codes to do the job of indicating success of failure.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas the reason I want to make my own verification rather than relying on the  HTML standard verification is because of the signature field, my understanding is that the standard HTML validation doesnt include signatures fields?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas I tried removing ` <?php include('form_process.php'); ?>` but it prevented the php sheet fom being added at all. Before hand the form_process.php was being included. I could tell as at the top of the page it had the error - `There was an Error!` which makes me think that there is an error in the `form_process.php` sheet

Comment: Remove `action="form_process.php"` this is what loading the page and add ajax to do post request then you can alter form-message content based on response.

Comment: What I meant is to do your validation via ja, and then via javascript as well send the data via `$.ajax`. The result will be a json or html and via javascript as well change your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:Include your own validation and flow:

```js
Your form_process.php

<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
    $signature = $_POST['signature'];
    $message = $_POST['messages'];
  //  $company = $_POST['company'];

    $ErrorEmpty = false;
    $ErrorEmail = false;

    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($signature)){
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Please fill in required fields</span>";
        $ErrorEmpty = true;
    }
    elseif(!empty($email) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Please 1fill in a valid email address</span>";
        $ErrorEmail = true;
    }   
    else {
        echo "<span class='form-success'>Sucess!!</span>";
    }
}



?>

index.php
```

```html
<?php include('form_process.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#frm1").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var signature = $("#signature").val();
                 var messages = $("#messages").val();
                 $.ajax({
            url:"form_process.php",
            type:"POST",
             data: { name: name, email :email, signature:signature,messages:messages,action:"process"} ,
         success:function(response) {
           $(".form-message").html(response);
        },
        error:function(){
         alert("error");
        }
       });
    });
  });
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="contact-form">
        <form id="frm1"  action="form_process.php" method="POST" >
            <div class="podrecieved">
                <h3>Recieved by<h3>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label for="firstname">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="John Doe">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label for="email_id">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email_id" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="john@company.com">
            </div>
            <div>                 
                <label for="messages">
                    <span class="required">Additional Comments:</span> 
                    <textarea id="messages" name="messages" placeholder="Please write your thougths here." tabindex="5"></textarea> 
                </label>  
            </div>   
            <div class="container">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h3>Click to sign</h3>
                                <input type="text" id="signature" name="signature" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="editor"></div>  
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
            <p class="form-message"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have ammended the code to this and I am getting the same outcome. I have no idea why. The PHP should validate the form and then send it but instead, the submit button is acting as a link to website.com/form_process.php. Is there an error with my submit button?